# change Apple developer account during development

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I was using my developer account for testing App .but now i want to use client's developer account but when i am using the same App Id . i am getting error

```
There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
An App ID with Identifier 'com.xyz.test' is not available. Please enter a different string.

i want to use same App id because i have used this in social logins and in push notifications settings .

how could i use this App Id for client account .please help
```

Comment: First of all you have to remove App ID from your developer account (If you haven't make it live ever, otherwise it's not possible to use same app ID). after deleting from your Account, you can assign same to client's account.

Comment: but my previous developer account has been expired

Comment: Then you can't use current one. App ID must be unique, to use it, you have to remove old one. Otherwise choose new one.

Comment: ok thanks @Dipak Kacha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very first thing I want to highlight that you cann't create same App Id (com.xyz.test) in multiple developer account even though that account belongs to you.

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.xyz.test' is not available. Please enter a different string.

- Apple don't allow to create multiple app using same app id. The app id **must be** unique.

> i want to use same App id because i have used this in social logins and in push notifications settings.

- Either you need to remove already used app id from account and then create that app id from your client's account and then create certificates, register devices, create provisioning profile, etc. again for this account. You need to repeat that process again for your client developer account.

If your account is expired then as far as I know you couldn't use that same app id for your app unless and until it is removed from that  account.